# Unable to add new tableview cell properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview, uiimage

I'm trying add new tableview cell with some delay. I'm creating delay with following piece of code.

```
func delay(delay:Double, closure:()->()) {
    dispatch_after(
        dispatch_time(
            DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
            Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))
        ),
        dispatch_get_main_queue(), closure)
}
```

I'm adding table view cell in using above function

```
delay(1){
     // adding tableview cell here 
  }
```

It's perfectly fine if i stay in same view controller but it's adding image in following way when i switch tabs during that delay.

[image]

I'm checking datasource and everything using breakpoints but I'm unable to find errors.

If i stay in same view controller. It's working fine [image]

Comment: Can you show us the screenshot of the view when you stay in your view controller? You said that the image is perfectly fine. In such way we could understand better what's the desired behaviour and eventually help.

Comment: @Andrej Please check i added it.

Comment: @chandramohan; try this [tableViewCell layoutIfNeeded] after setting the data into the tableviewCell.

Comment: @chandramohan, let me know if it works...

Comment: No @SiddharthSunil. I tried it. Actually height and width of my tableview cells are dyncamic. can i force my layout?.

Comment: @chandramohan, can you share your code so that I can figure out a way to solve your problem. & [tableViewCell layoutIfNeeded] does not force the layout intact it adjusts the layout according to the cell data. Share your code  then only I can provide exact solution.